# How to write trait in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, traits

Traits are much more efficient than behaviors as behaviors are objects that take both time and memory.so can anyone explain how i can write trait in yii2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In General:

> A Trait is similar to a class, but only intended to group functionality in a fine-grained and consistent way. It is not possible to instantiate a Trait on its own.

```
<?php
trait Hello {
    public function sayHello() {
        echo 'Hello ';
    }
}

trait World {
    public function sayWorld() {
        echo 'World';
    }
}

class MyHelloWorld {
    use Hello, World;
    public function sayExclamationMark() {
        echo '!';
    }
}

$o = new MyHelloWorld();
$o->sayHello();
$o->sayWorld();
$o->sayExclamationMark();
?>
```

#### Use behavior then traits mainly for YII.

Check this out:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html#comparison-with-traits

#### Reasons to Use Behaviors:

Behavior classes, like normal classes, support inheritance. Traits, on the other hand, can be considered as language-supported copy and paste. They do not support inheritance.

Comment: Traits good too. But according to Yii2 dev it's a good practice to use namespaces for traits