# Yii2 call method/function of a different model

Tags: php, oop, model, yii2, virtual-attribute

I have a method/function of a virtual attribute in `Model1`:

```
class Model1 {
    public $virtattr;
    public $_virtattr;

    public function getVirtattr () {
        if (isset($this->_virtattr)) {
            return $this->_virtattr;
        }

        return $this->_virtattr = str_ireplace('x1', 'x2', $this->virtattr);
    }
}
```

How can I call this method in `Model2` to get the same result?
I was trying it this way but unfortunately it's not working, 'cause I'm getting empty results:

```
use Model1;

class Model2 {
    public $virtattr;
    public $_virtattr;

    public function getVirtattr () {
        return (new Model1)->getVirtattr();
    }
}
```

Can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: `Model1::getVirtattr();` but you'r way is also correct

Comment: But how do I'm getting empty result then...? I can't use `Model1::getVirtattr();` because it's not a static

Comment: what are you receiving and what do you expect to recieve?

Comment: why you defined $virtattr variable when you defined getVirtattr function?

Comment: It looks like you need to learn some OOP basics. You should probably take a look at traits: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: Definitely! I never said I shouldn't :D Thanks for the tip, I've never really met with traits regarding yii. I'm going to check it.

Comment: based on this I've managed to make it work! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649600/how-to-write-trait-in-yii2 Thank you! Would you answer me to be able to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of object programming is encapsulation - `Model1` will not magically use properties from `Model2` just because you instantiated `Model1` inside of `Model2`. `Model1` will use its own properties so `(new Model1())->getVirtattr()` will not touch properties  from `Model2`.

If you want to share the same logic between two classes, you may use inheritance:

```
class Model1 {

    public $virtattr;
    public $_virtattr;

    public function getVirtattr() {
        if ($this->_virtattr !== null) {
            return $this->_virtattr;
        }

        return $this->_virtattr = str_ireplace('x1', 'x2', $this->virtattr);
    }
}

class Model2 extends Model1 {

}
```

Then `Model1::getVirtattr()` and `Model2::getVirtattr()` will use the same implementation.

If inheritance is not possible/preferred, you may use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to share the same implementation between two separate classes:

```
trait VirtattrTrait {

    public $virtattr;
    public $_virtattr;

    public function getVirtattr() {
        if ($this->_virtattr !== null) {
            return $this->_virtattr;
        }

        return $this->_virtattr = str_ireplace('x1', 'x2', $this->virtattr);
    }
}

class Model1 {

    use VirtattrTrait;
}

class Model2 {

    use VirtattrTrait;
}
```